# Extract Date from a string using Derived Column in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a column called FileName and I wanted extract the date from the column as a Date column using Derived Column in SSIS. The FileName Data type is nvarchar(260)

FileName

> M:\Mapping\Workforce_Planning\ABC\ABClrmp.full.2016-01-07.csv

**Desired Result**

```
2016-01-07
```

I have been using SQL task but I prefer to use Derived Column.

```
Update [dbo].[GET]
SET [Date] = CONVERT(date, REPLACE(SUBSTRING([FileName], LEN([FileName])-CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([FileName]),0)+2, LEN([FileName])-(LEN([FileName])- CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([FileName]),0))),'.csv',''), 121)
```

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See How to Ask for help with asking a great question.

Comment: You can just as easily build the conversion in SSIS - Use `Expression` field

Comment: @Djbril Again, you are supposed to show an effort in trying to solve a problem. A simple Google search returns dozens of high-quality tutorials and examples of how to use Expression Builder in SSIS (here is an example http://pragmaticworks.com/Training/Resources/Cheat-Sheets/SSIS-Expression-Cheat-Sheet). It is very similar to what you have in SQL; if you try something and it doesn't work - come here for help. Generally people won't even try to help you if you don't show any effort in solving it yourself.

Comment: @Djbril or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711349/ssis-expression-convert-date-to-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a derived column with the following expression

```
LEFT(RIGHT([Filename],14),10)
```

Read more about `Derived  Column Transformation` in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx)

**Test**

i tested this expression on the following path `M:\Mapping\Workforce_Planning\ABC\ABClrmp.full.2016-01-07.csv` and it gives the following result `2016-01-07`